# SQL compare using between for separated Date and Time Column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have two columns.

CREATED_DATE || CREATED_TIME

And I want to write a query to get records between these columns. 
I wrote below query but it fails because of time column.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE (CREATE_DATE BETWEEN '1982-10-21' AND '2015-02-25')
       `AND (CREATE_TIME BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '15:00:00')
```

However if requested_start_date >= created_date and requested_end_date =< created_date it then SQL should not compare time columns.
How can i handle it?

Thank you 
Regeards

Comment: Actually, it fails, because of the `FROM`. Where is your `FROM`?

Comment: Would you consider changing the design to a DATETIME column? It would make this case and propable future cases much easier. Keeping these values in two columns is bad practice in the long run.

Comment: It's unclear, which rows you want to select. Describe in more detail.

Comment: @Ziouas You don't know the use-case. Separating date and time in two columns might make perfect sense.

Comment: @Ziouas you are right i told to SAP developers, unfortunately it is not possible. Integration with SAP is so hard

Comment: substitute "`AND" with "AND"?

Comment: @fancyPants It may be, but it's much easier and faster to extract time and date from datetime for presentation puropses than to do such comparisons based on two columns every time. From the effectiveness point of view of course. If the db is small then it's not an issue at all.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the query. The query is written to get all entries between the two dates that were created in the afternoon. So, although there are entries with create_time in the afternoon, they don't get selected? Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

select *from TABLE 
where CAST(CREATE_TIME as time) >= '14:00:00' 
or CAST(CREATE_TIME as time) < '15:00:00'
try this for time comparision

Comment: dear @neel shah thank you but, how about date column

Comment: try it as you are doing it now 'where Date AND Time'

Comment: @WinstonSmith Again, describe in more detail which rows should be selected. Multiple answers possible, and except neel shah here noone is in the mood to guess around.

Comment: @fancyPants think like that: there is only 1 column as created_date (yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss) and my customer sends me two dates (start and end) My customer requests records which created_date is between start and end date. But I have to keep date records in two columns (date + time) I wish to it is clear now